# Sawtooth Software installation error indicates I have the wrong processor achitecture. My Windows device specifications indicates the opposite

Tags: macos, virtualization, windows-11, parallels

I am running Parallels Desktop on a MacBook Pro (Big Sur 11.5.2) with an Apple M1 chip. I’m trying to install Lighthouse Studio from Sawtooth Software, but it gives me an error message in which it states that:

> “This program can only be installed on versions of Windows designed for the following processor architectures: x86, x64”

When checking the device specifications in Parallels, it indicates that the system type should be a 64-bit operating system.

> [image: Here is a screenshot that shows both my device specs and the error message]

Why does Sawtooth Software fail to install Lighthouse Studio? Is it due to the fact that I’m using Parallels?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Your screenshots clearly indicate your system has an ARM processor, an ARM processor, is not an x86_x64 processor.  The only way to run Windows on an M1 Apple machine that I was tracking is to run Windows 11 on ARM. Your screenshots indicate your running an AArch64 compatible operating system. Windows 11 on ARM to my knowlege can NOT run x64 Windows applications

Comment: I guess my question is how to properly install the required uni-software for the hardware I have. For Mac-owners they suggested using Parallels to virtualize a Windows-device, and install the required software on that.
Parallels defaulted to Windows 11, I don't know how I would run W10, or whether that's compatible with the software the university requires me to install. I'm unfortunately very green in this area.

Comment: “Parallels defaulted to Windows 11, I don't know how I would run W10, or whether that's compatible with the software the university requires me to install. I'm unfortunately very green in this area.” Your university is giving you incorrect/uneducated information. This has utterly nothing to do with Windows 11, Windows 10 or any other version. The Windows 11 installed on your M1-based Mac is specifically built for ARM-based CPUs which is what an M1-based Mac. Unless Lighthouse Studio is released with an ARM version, it cannot run on an M1-based Mac.

Comment: @Namrad - **You don't on the hardware you have.** The software you are asking about is incompatible with the hardware you have.

Comment: @Ramhound To be 100% fair to Namrad even I was getting mixed messages about Intel-based software on M1-based Macs. When I heard Parallels could be used the general info I was getting from colleagues was Parallels was using the speed of the Apple M1 to actually emulate an Intel CPU architecture. Which sounded great! It was only when I actually did my own research I found out that Microsoft was only releasing an ARM-based version of Windows and the hype that Parallels was putting out was “truthy”; yeah Windows could run on an M1 with Parallels, but not all software would be compatible with that.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Microsoft has not release any version designed to run on M1 Apple hardware.  The fact `Windows 10 on ARM` and `Windows 11 on ARM` can run on M1 Apple hardware is due to the fact the M1 is compatible with it.  Don't get me started on the fact it's impossible to be properly licensed, since those editions of Windows, are only sold with certain Microsoft blessed ARM devices.  Those editions of Windows are licensed separate from x86/x64 editions of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound You are really nit-picking. Let’s just agree that Apple’s M1 push was not handled well as far as non-Apple developers using Apple hardware goes.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - I am an Engineer.  Details are the difference between crashing a drone into the moon because of the difference in meters and feet.  I thought the Windows 11 announcement, was going to be an announcement, that would indicate that Windows on ARM was going to be sold to M1 Apple device owners through a partnership deal with Apple.  I made a ton of money purchasing Microsoft stock, since anything connected to Apple turns to literal gold, I guessed the correct reaction but not the correct reason for said reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An Apple M1 CPU is an ARM-based processor and the software is clearly looking for an Intel-based processor.

The issue is not the 64-bit part, but the Apple M1 being an ARM-based CPU and Lighthouse Studio is looking for an Intel-based CPU.

Look at your Parallels settings:

> “64-bit operating system, ARM-based processor”

And look at the error message you got again:

> “This program can only be installed on versions of Windows designed for the following processor architectures: x86, x64”

That x86 indicates “Intel 32-bit” and the x64 indicates “Intel 64-bit” and neither are related to the ARM-based architecture the Apple M1 CPU is based on.

So yes, you are running Windows on a macOS system, but Parallels is *not* an emulator, but rather is a [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) that allows you to allocate your systems resources for virtual machines. Meaning the version of Windows you are running in that virtual machine is an ARM-based version of Windows and *not* an Intel-based version of Windows which is what Lighthouse Studio is looking for.

Also, look at this support thread on Sawtooth Software’s own website: “[Running Lighthouse Studio on Windows ARM VM via Parallels for Mac with M1 Chip](https://legacy.sawtoothsoftware.com/forum/30157/running-lighthouse-studio-windows-parallels-mac-with-chip)”

The question there is effectively the same as this question here and the official answer is the same as what others, such as me, are posting here:

> “Lighthouse uses components that require an x86 or x64 environment. Unfortunately there is no way around this.”

FWIW, compatibility stuff like this is why I am currently using the last Intel-based MacBook Air Apple put out: The early 2020 model. A lot of my work requires me spinning up some Linux VMs in VirtualBox and ARM VMs don’t cut it yet. So until someone comes up with a way to virtualize Intel CPUs on ARM, I am stuck with an Intel-based Mac. –

Comment: Thanks for your input Giacomo. You've made it crystal clear. I won't be able to make this work with what I've got, and I thereby have no chance of solving this myself. Will contact the uni duly. Sorry for not having checked with Lighthouse first. I appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Windows indicates that it is 64-bit, but Arm-based.

This application only runs on x86 / x64. not Arm. I believe Parallels is using an Arm-based windows client, so this isn't likely to work.

you are also not the first to bump into this issue. have a look here;

https://legacy.sawtoothsoftware.com/forum/30157/running-lighthouse-studio-windows-parallels-mac-with-chip

the best suggested solution is to use windows, unfortunately.

Comment: I should have looked at Lighthouses forums first. This post makes it ultra-clear that I can't achieve what I'm looking for with what I have.
Thanks for your input jrdnjhnstn!